# pandas keyError "Retries" error while reading csv file

Tags: pandas

```
        df = pd.read_csv('/home/hadoop/data.csv')
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
        return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 482, in _read
        parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 811, in __init__
        self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine
        return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 51, in __init__
        self._open_handles(src, kwds)
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/base_parser.py", line 229, in _open_handles
        errors=kwds.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 614, in get_handle
        storage_options=storage_options,
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 359, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
        filepath_or_buffer, mode=fsspec_mode, **(storage_options or {})
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 140, in open
        out = self.__enter__()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 103, in __enter__
        f = self.fs.open(self.path, mode=mode)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1015, in open
        **kwargs,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 564, in _open
        cache_options=cache_options,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1809, in __init__
        cache_options=cache_options,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1351, in __init__
        self.size = self.details["size"]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1364, in details
        self._details = self.fs.info(self.path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 91, in wrapper
        return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 71, in sync
        raise return_result
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 25, in _runner
        result[0] = await coro
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1035, in _info
        **self.req_kw,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 281, in _call_s3
        raise err
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 261, in _call_s3
        out = await method(**additional_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 174, in _make_api_call
        operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 193, in _make_request
        return await self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 83, in _send_request
        exception):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 216, in _needs_retry
        caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/hooks.py", line 29, in _emit
        response = handler(**kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 189, in __call__
        retries_context = kwargs['request_dict']['context']['retries']
    KeyError: 'retries'
```

The above error is thrown While reading a csv file.  Pandas version is 1.3.1

Comment: Hi @Kicha, thanks for asking a question and welcome to the community. Please refer to the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to correctly ask a question so that it can be helpful to everyone. E.g. Place the code and define your environment so others can replicate the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.